# OleDB Connection String to MySQL Connection String

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have this OleDB code which basically reads an excel file and displays it on to the datagridview after a button click:

```
string pathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + txtPath.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(pathConn);

OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + txtSheet.Text + "$]", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);

dgvViewDrivers.DataSource = dt;
```

My question is that how would I make a MySQL Connection out of this OleDB connection string? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MySQL .NET connector

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + 
    database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";"))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "sql here";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**Your current code**

This

```
using (vDBCon = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;Data Source=" + txtPath.Text + ";user=root;PASSWORD= ;"))
```

txtPath.Text needs to be the name of your database in MySQL. I assume you left the password out. If not you need one.

```
"SERVER=localhost;Data Source=MyDatabase;user=root;PASSWORD=MyPassword;"
```

where MyDatabase is the actual name of your database and MyPassword is the password you use to login with

You have to actually be running MySQL Server itself to create and connect to a MySQL database. it doesn't work of a file like Access. If you want something like that just use SQLite.

this

```
vCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + txtSheet.Text + "$]";
```

this you will be selecting data from your table in MySQL so it needs to look like

```
vCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
```

where MyTable is actually the name of your table in the database

Comment: hello thanks for answering I already have the connector. My problem is the syntax because I am not familiar with it sorry.

Comment: Everthing works the same except when you add the database you will use the connection string I posted. Items will have MySql in front of it when you include the namespace. MySqlCommand, MySqlConnection, MySqlDataAdapter ..ex

Comment: using (vDBCon = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;Data Source=" + txtPath.Text + ";user=root;PASSWORD= ;"))
            {
                vDBCon.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand vCmd = vDBCon.CreateCommand())
                {
                    vCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + txtSheet.Text + "$]";
                    vReader = vCmd.ExecuteReader();

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(vReader);

                    dgvViewDrivers.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }

Comment: Is this correct? I have an error it says that unable to connect to specified hosts. Basically the datasource comes from an open file dialog which directs to the path of the excel like C://Users/....